# jquery load multiple parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two parts in my website what are used in on multiple pages.
I use jquery load to make these parts visible in a div on the webpages.

For each part I use a different script. But I wonder if there is an smarter way to do this.

html:

```
<div id="prijsLijstVD"></div> 
<div id="colofon"></div>
```

scripts

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#colofon").load("info.html");
    ;
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#prijsLijstVD").load("info_prijs_vd.html");
    ;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you declaring two document ready?

Comment: because i dont know how to make it work otherwise.